# Rendering html in PLAY using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, templates, playframework

I am newly struggling with PLAY using play-1.2.5 version. I have the knowledge that render() will display a page with the name same as of the method where it is called. (Please correct if wrong)

So, As the callback is optional for $.get() method, I wrote following code in jQuery on a html page,:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#next").click(function(){
                $.get("/nextpage");
            });
        });
```

having my route file set, it should hit my Firstpage method which is as follows:

```
 public static void Firstpage(){
        Logger.info("Reached first page");
        render();
    }
```

What I think is my Firstpage.html (which is a pure html, nothing of templates do I know) should load on screen once I execute it. jQuery is all fine and my Log of this method is also printed on console.
So where am I wrong. Can't pure html be loaded this way and I will have to go for learning templates and all.

Please have a say.

Comment: Add information about Play version

Comment: Pls anyone care to lend a hand here...

Comment: Why am I not getting a response here since so many days